# How to get wallet tokens balance with the help of address and tokens contracts?

Tags: wallets, contract, tokens

I have a wallet address and token contracts

For example:

wallet address: **tz1MmduNCzoKU9GHngwLqC8TmExTHQXJCSTn**

and Tokens contracts:

Plenty: **KT1GRSvLoikDsXujKgZPsGLX8k8VvR2Tq95b**

Quipu: **KT193D4vozYnhGJQVtw7CoxxqphqUEEwK6Vb**

ecoin: **KT1M81KrJr6TxYLkZkVqcpSTNKGoya8XytWT**

Youves: **KT1Xobej4mc6XgEjDoJoHtTKgbD1ELMvcQuL**

Uno: **KT1ErKVqEhG9jxXgUG2KGLW3bNM7zXHX8SD**

kolibriUSD: **KT1K9gCRgaLRFKTErYt1wVxA3Frb9FjasjTV**

usdTz: **KT1LN4LPSqTMS7Sd2CJw4bbDGRkMv2t68Fy9**

Ctez: **KT1SjXiUX63QvdNMcM2m492f7kuf8JxXRLp4**

Dogami: **KT1Ha4yFVeyzw6KRAdkzq6TxDHB97KG4pZe8**

=============

I want to show the balance of every above contract with the help of a wallet address.

Is there any API to help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to use an indexer that is aware of all tokens. Its not scalable to query them one at a time from the RPC, or to maintain the list of tokens.

This API from TZKT:
https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Tokens_GetTokenBalances

Only needs a wallet address, and will return balances for up to 10,000 tokens per page/request

Comment: How to filter just specific tokens balance?

Comment: @Taleb the link lists all the query parameters available. `token.contract` can be used to filter specific contract addresses